# How to populate pandas DataFrame based on multiple columns and conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on a hobby project, but I am stuck on populating a DataFrame in pandas. I have three DataFrames. My problems:

- For each `id` in `DataFrame1`, add column `n` to column `x` in `DataFrame3` if column `m` is equal to `1`.
- For each `id` in `DataFrame1` and `DataFrame2` set column `y` to `1` if column `c` in `DataFrame1` is equal to `1` or if column `d` in `DataFrame2` is equal to `1`. `c` equal to `99` has highest priority and sets `y` to `99`

Can anyone please help me?

```
DataFrame1

    | id     | n    | m | c |
    |--------|------|---|---|
    | 577140 | bla1 | 0 | 0 |
    | 577140 | bla2 | 0 | 0 |
    | 577140 | bla3 | 0 | 0 |
    | 577140 | bla4 | 1 | 0 |
    | 577140 | bla5 | 0 | 1 |
    | 577141 | bla6 | 0 | 0 |
    | 577141 | bla7 | 0 | 0 |
    | 577141 | bla8 | 1 | 0 |

DataFrame2

    | id     | d |
    |--------|---|
    | 577140 | 1 |
    | 577141 | 0 |

DataFrame3 (currently)

    | id     |
    |--------|
    | 577140 |
    | 577141 |

DataFrame3 (needed)

    | id     | x    | y |
    |--------|------|---|
    | 577140 | bla4 | 1 |
    | 577141 | bla8 | 0 |
```

Comment: Do you have an attempt?

Comment: I tried some stuff with ‘’’apply’’’ but it didn’t work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to chain use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) twice to join all 3 dataframes and after that conditionally make the `y` column with [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) which we can pass multiple conditions

```
df_temp = pd.merge(df3, df1[df1.m == 1], on='id').merge(df2, on='id')

# Create column y with multiple conditions
conditions = [
    df_temp['c'] == 99,
    (df_temp['c'] == 1) | (df_temp['d'] == 1)
]

choices = [99, 1]

df_temp['y'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)

# Select only columns we need for output
df_final = df_temp[['id', 'n', 'y']]

print(df_final)
       id     n  y
0  577140  bla4  1
1  577141  bla8  0
```

Comment: I just realized I can have a `99` in column `c` as well. So column `y` should be set to `99` when `c` is equal to `99`. How does this affect this code?

Comment: `c=99` --> `y=99`, `c=1 or d=1` ->`y=1`, else `y=0`

Comment: @dunkubok I edited the answer based on your new addition

Answer (score 0):

Try using `merge`:

```
DataFrame3 = DataFrame3.merge(DataFrame1, how='left')
DataFrame3 = DataFrame3.merge(DataFrame2, how='left')
DataFrame3 = DataFrame3.rename(columns={'n': 'x'})
DataFrame3 = DataFrame3[DataFrame3['m'] == 1]
DataFrame3['y'] = (DataFrame3['c'] | DataFrame3['d'])
DataFrame3.drop(columns=['c', 'd', 'm'])
```

Comment: Please take a look at my comment under @Erfan's post

Answer (score 0):

I used a `set` for the "if column c in DataFrame1 is equal to 1 or if column d is 1" logic:

```
columns = ['id', 'n', 'm', 'c']

df1=pd.DataFrame(
    [[577140, 'bla1', 0, 0],
    [577140, 'bla2', 0, 0],
    [577140, 'bla3', 0, 0],
    [577140, 'bla4', 1, 0],
    [577140, 'bla5', 0, 1],
    [577141, 'bla6', 0, 0],
    [577141, 'bla7', 0, 0],
    [577141, 'bla8', 1, 0]], columns=columns)

df3 = df1.loc[df1.m == 1, ['id', 'n']]
df3.columns = ['id', 'x']

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[577140, 1], [577141, 0]], columns=['id', 'd'])

id_set = set([df1[df1.c == 1]['id'].values[0], df2[df2.d == 1]['id'].values[0]])

df3['y'] = 0

df3.loc[df3.id.isin(id_set), 'y'] = 1
```

Comment: Please take a look at my comment under @Erfan's post

Comment: If "c" can take on multiple values, it's better to use the `merge` options since that will retain the value of `c` to give to `y`.